# GetSelectedFields Returning Gridview DevExpress

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, webforms, devexpress

I am using DevExpress to create a table with a form within it. On a button click I want to take the data from the selected row and insert it into a table of mine.

On the serverside I am having difficulty getting the selectedfieldvalues. I have followed DevExpress tutorials and can't seem to get the selected fields values. My list keeps returning 0.

Please see my code so far..

[server side code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jYMto.png)

[client side code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/innur.png)

Comment: FYI: It's expected that you post your code, and not images.   For one, it's easier for someone to copy your code in order to help formulate a solution, as well as the image urls might not work in the future so this thread could be useless to someone trying to use it as a reference.

Comment: Why don't you contact the DevExpress Support directly?